# Extract consecutive bouts by time and date

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe `dat` with the headers `Date` `Hour` and `TYPE` as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "04/20/17", class = "factor"), 
    Hour = c("14:30:00", "14:31:00", "14:32:00", "14:33:00", 
    "14:34:00", "14:35:00", "14:36:00", "14:37:00", "14:38:00", 
    "14:39:00", "14:40:00", "14:41:00", "14:42:00", "14:43:00", 
    "14:44:00", "14:45:00", "14:46:00", "14:47:00", "14:48:00", 
    "14:49:00", "14:50:00", "14:51:00", "14:52:00", "14:53:00", 
    "14:54:00", "14:55:00", "14:56:00", "14:57:00", "14:58:00", 
    "14:59:00", "15:00:00", "15:01:00", "15:02:00", "15:03:00", 
    "15:04:00", "15:05:00", "15:06:00", "15:07:00", "15:08:00", 
    "15:09:00", "15:10:00", "15:11:00", "15:12:00", "15:13:00", 
    "15:14:00", "15:15:00", "15:16:00", "15:17:00", "15:18:00", 
    "15:19:00", "15:20:00", "15:21:00", "15:22:00", "15:23:00", 
    "15:24:00", "15:25:00", "15:26:00", "15:27:00", "15:28:00", 
    "15:29:00", "15:30:00", "15:31:00", "15:32:00", "15:33:00", 
    "15:34:00", "15:35:00", "15:36:00", "15:37:00", "15:38:00", 
    "15:39:00", "15:40:00", "15:41:00", "15:42:00", "15:43:00", 
    "15:44:00", "15:45:00", "15:46:00", "15:47:00", "15:48:00", 
    "15:49:00", "15:50:00", "15:51:00", "15:52:00", "15:53:00", 
    "15:54:00", "15:55:00", "15:56:00", "15:57:00", "15:58:00", 
    "15:59:00", "16:00:00", "16:01:00", "16:02:00", "16:03:00", 
    "16:04:00", "16:05:00", "16:06:00", "16:07:00", "16:08:00", 
    "16:09:00", "16:10:00", "16:11:00", "16:12:00", "16:13:00", 
    "16:14:00", "16:15:00", "16:16:00", "16:17:00", "16:18:00", 
    "16:19:00", "16:20:00", "16:21:00", "16:22:00", "16:23:00", 
    "16:24:00", "16:25:00", "16:26:00", "16:27:00", "16:28:00", 
    "16:29:00", "16:30:00", "16:31:00", "16:32:00", "16:33:00", 
    "16:34:00"), TYPE = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Hour", "TYPE"), row.names = 2:126, class = "data.frame")
```

In this example dataframe `Date` only represents a single day but there could be many. `TYPE` is numeric and corresponds to a behaviour undertaken (1-3).

**Background:**
Similar `TYPE`numbers that follow consecutively indicate the same behaviour being undertaken. So between 14:30:00 and 14:37:00 for example a single behaviour was undertaken and I'd like to term this a single `Bout`

**My question:**
How could I sort the data so that I end up with a dataframe such as this:

**EDITED TO INCLUDE NEXT DAY:**

```
  Date      Bout   Start      End      TYPE
4/20/17      1   14:30:00   14:37:00     3
4/20/17      2   14:38:00   15:27:00     1
4/20/17      3   15:28:00   16:03:00     2
4/20/17      4   16:04:00   16:23:00     1
4/20/17      5   16:24:00   16:34:00     3 
4/21/17      1   13:00:00   13:01:00     1
4/21/17      2   13:02:00   13:05:00     2
```

I would like to group them according to `Date` also so here the dates would begin `4/20/17`, the next (although not shown in the example) would be `4/21/17.`

I have gathered similar data using `aggregate` for example:

`setNames(aggregate(cbind(dat$TYPE == 1, dat$TYPE == 2, dat$TYPE == 3), by=list(Category=dat$Date), FUN = sum), c("Date", "Standing", "Lying_right", "Lying_left"))` but cannot figure how to use it in this context. Maybe a function could be placed into `FUN` in `aggregate`?

Comment: Some great answers below that all work well. But will go with @Sotos for first answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`. The grouping of `Bout` takes the cumsum of the values where the difference is not equal to 0 (i.e. different values).

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Date, Bout = cumsum(c(1, diff(TYPE) != 0))) %>% 
  summarise(start = head(Hour, 1), 
              End = tail(Hour, 1), 
             TYPE = unique(TYPE))

#Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#Groups: Date [?]

#      Date  Bout    start      End   TYPE
#    <fctr> <dbl>    <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 04/20/17     1 14:30:00 14:37:00     3
#2 04/20/17     2 14:38:00 15:27:00     1
#3 04/20/17     3 15:28:00 16:03:00     2
#4 04/20/17     4 16:04:00 16:23:00     1
#5 04/20/17     5 16:24:00 16:34:00     3
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset Bout each day? I have edited the table in the post to explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[,.(Date=first(Date),Start=first(Hour),End=last(Hour)),by=.(Bout=rleid(TYPE),TYPE)]
# Bout TYPE     Date    Start      End
# 1:    1    3 04/20/17 14:30:00 14:37:00
# 2:    2    1 04/20/17 14:38:00 15:27:00
# 3:    3    2 04/20/17 15:28:00 16:03:00
# 4:    4    1 04/20/17 16:04:00 16:23:00
# 5:    5    3 04/20/17 16:24:00 16:34:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` solution. Treating Date and Time as timestamps so that being able to with the case when a bout spans two days.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, timestamp := strptime(paste(as.character(Date), Hour), format = "%m/%d/%y %T")]
dat[, bout_id := rep(seq(length(rle(TYPE)$values)),  rle(TYPE)$lengths)]
dat[, list(Start = min(timestamp), End = max(timestamp), TYPE = TYPE[1]),by = bout_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that works for a single day using `rle` and `reshape`.

```
# get information on the length of each bout
temp <- rle(dat$TYPE)
stoppers <- cumsum(temp$lengths)
stoppers <- sort(c(1, stoppers, head(stoppers + 1, -1)))

# subset data according to start and stop point of each bout
datNew <- dat[stoppers, ]
# provide id for each bout
datNew$Bout <- rep(seq_along(temp$lengths), each=2)
# provide start and stop value
datNew$timevar <- 1:2
```

Now, reshaping wide produces

```
reshape(datNew, idvar="Bout", direction="wide", v.names="Hour", timevar="timevar")
        Date TYPE Bout   Hour.1   Hour.2
2   04/20/17    3    1 14:30:00 14:37:00
10  04/20/17    1    2 14:38:00 15:27:00
60  04/20/17    2    3 15:28:00 16:03:00
96  04/20/17    1    4 16:04:00 16:23:00
116 04/20/17    3    5 16:24:00 16:34:00
```

If you want to perform this for separate dates, you would split the data.frame into a list of data.frames on date, apply the above as a function to each data.frame, and then use `do.call` with `rbind` on the result to combine each date. This would look something like

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(dat, dat$Date), function(x) {
          temp <- rle(x$TYPE)
          stoppers <- cumsum(temp$lengths)
          stoppers <- sort(c(1, stoppers, head(stoppers + 1, -1)))

          # subset data according to start and stop point of each bout
          datNew <- x[stoppers, ]
          # provide id for each bout
          datNew$Bout <- rep(seq_along(temp$lengths), each=2)
          # provide start and stop value
          datNew$timevar <- 1:2

          reshape(datNew, idvar="Bout", direction="wide", v.names="Hour", timevar="timevar")
}))
```